# Wrong status code in ASP.NET Core middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware

I have a problem in a simple piece of middleware I've created. The status code of the response is 200, even though I throw an exception in my controller action and the status code returned to the client is 500.

My middleware looks like this:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // context.Response.StatusCode == 200
        throw;
    }
}
```

It looks like the logic transforming the exception to 500 happens at a later step in the middleware pipeline.

The `Configure` method in `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Notice that I'm not using `UseExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Are you using any filters anywhere?

Comment: I duplicated what you have here and I get a 500 result when I just put a `throw new Exception();' in a controller method.  Do you know what is throwing the exception to begin with?

Comment: No filter. I throw the exception with throw new Exception. Do you see the 500 in the middleware or when expecting the response on the client?

Comment: @nurdyguy I just tried creating a blank project. The status code is still 200 when entering the catch block in the middleware. I think this is the default behavior and that the code translating to 500 happens at a later stage.

Comment: @ThomasArdal Ah, I see what you are saying now.  I'd guess that since a response has not yet been created (because we exited on an exception) then something later in the pipe will have to take care of building the response.  Why are you concerned with this?  Just curiosity or is there something else you are trying to do?

Comment: @nurdyguy I want to log the error including the correct status code.

Comment: @ThomasArdal Well, at that point in the pipe it doesn't yet have a status code (other than the default 200) so you can't really log based on that.  You could create an exception class, extending Exception, and put specific status codes on the error when you throw it.  Your standard unhandled exceptions will still be 500s but other things can be more specific.

Comment: Note that if the response has already started sending to the client then the status code can no longer be changed.